# Getting a value from one class to another

Tags: java

```
private void update(float delta) {

    playerRectangle.setPosition(getX() + velocity.x * delta, 300);

    setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);

}
```

So let's say I have the above method in ClassA but I want to use

```
playerRectangle.setPosition(getX() + velocity.x * delta, 300);
```

for ClassB, however, delta would not defined in ClassB, so I was wondering how would I get the delta value?

*I made getter methods for velocity and playerRectangle in ClassA

```
public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor{

private Vector2 velocity;
private float speed = 500;
private Rectangle playerRectangle, rightRectangle, leftRectangle;

public Player(Sprite sprite){
    super(sprite);
    playerRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,286,160);
    rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
    leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);
    velocity = new Vector2(0,0);

}

public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
    update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    super.draw(spriteBatch);
}

private void update(float delta) {

    playerRectangle.setPosition(getX() + velocity.x * delta, 300);

    setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);

}

public Rectangle getPlayerRectangle(){
    return playerRectangle;
}

public Rectangle getRightRectangle(){
    return rightRectangle;
}

public Rectangle getLeftRectangle(){
    return leftRectangle;
}

public Vector2 getVelocity(){
    return velocity;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide us with the code of classes.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `velocity` and `playerRectangle` classes?

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated it.

Comment: This question is very unclear. `delta` is just an argument being passed to a method. What's stopping you from passing the same value to another method on another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do

```
ClassA obj= new ClassA();
obj.playerRectangle.setPosition(obj.getX() + obj.velocity.x * obj.delta, 300);
```

> this will only work if all the functions and
>   objects( **ie;** getx(),velocity.x,delta ) are all public.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it. ClassA takes in a Sprite if that matters

Comment: I believe that will work if the variables are public. But with private you cannot access any function inside, since its scope is within the class. Extending a class won't really block anything. Its all Objects and variables from JVM.

Comment: The thing is, I have to make the field 'delta' in ClassA, but I would like to use the update method's 'delta'.

Comment: you cant call a private method from outside, you can create a public function and call the update function from that. Else change the update function public. And as i can see the `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` is a static value so you can get that from anywhere.!! Chose any of the option.

Comment: Right, I did that. I made it public and still yields same result if I were to do 'obj.delta' and Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() doesn't seem to work but I'll try looking into it.

Comment: If I were to type 'obj.delta' into my ClassB, it would underline 'delta' red and if I were to hover over it, it says 'delta cannot be resolved or is not a field' and two quick fixes are: 'Create field 'delta' in type 'ClassA' and 'Create constant 'delta' in type 'ClassA'. ClassA is the above code I posted (the Player class).

Comment: delta is just a function parameter, you must get the value from the `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`

Answer (score 0):

Include a setPlayerRectangle method in your Player class

```
public void setPlayerRectangle(Rectangle rectangleObject){
    playerRectangle= rectangleObject;
}
```

Then

```
Player playerObj = new Player(spriteObject);
....
....
// Create a new Rectangle object with/without arguments as per your need
Rectangle yourRectangle = new Rectangle();
yourRectangle.setPosition(getX() + playerObj.getVelocity().x *deltaValue, 300);
```

You didn't mention where is the getX() method defined, if its in the Player class,
then write playerObj.getX()..
 and then set it to playerObj

```
playerObj.setPlayerRectangle(yourRectangle);
```